# Accessing global variable with this-> pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
void val();
int v=10;

class test{
public:
    int v=11;
    void val()
    {
        printv();
    }
private:
    void printv()
    {
        int v=12;
        printf("V: %d",this->v);
    }
};

int main()
{
    test obj;
    obj.val();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting 11 as output but I need to access the global variable, How can I get it ??
Similarly are there any ways to access global variables with the same name as local variables in C & Python ??

Comment: Use `::v`.  Better, don't write such code in the first place.

Comment: *Similarly are there any ways to access global variables with the same name as local variables in C & Python* -- Advice -- pretend that C and Python do not exist.  Do not use other languages as a model in writing proper C++ code.

Comment: C and Python are two separate questions that would belong in separate posts.  However, search carefully first as they have almost surely been asked and answered before.  For C the only way I know is to declare `extern int v;` inside a nested block.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks Nate . Yeah sure it's just for testing purpose, anyways thanks a lot Nate.